# Reflection: Set properties of basetype

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to use Reflection to convert a KeyValuePair to different Properties of an object. These Properties can be simple Types or Complex types. If they are properties of the "BaseClass" type I want to assign the Id and Name:

My Classes:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
  public int Id { get;set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Person:MyBaseClass {
  public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Item:MyBaseClass {
  public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class TargetClass {
  public Person Chief {get;set;}
  public Item Product {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to use Reflection to assign the values:

```
foreach (var field in Fields) {
    var target=targetType.GetProperty(field.Key);
    if (field.Value.indexOf("|")>0) {
       int id=int.Parse(field.Value.Split('|')[0]);
       string name=field.Value.Split('|')[1];
       var baseObj = new MyBaseClass { Id = id, Name=name };
       target.SetValue(dest, baseObj);
    } else {
       target.SetValue(dest,field.Value);
    }
}
```

So if the field contains a "|" I want to split that value in an `Id` and a `Title` and Assign them to the target type.

`Fields` is a Dictionary of  `targetType` is `typeof(TargetClass)` and `dest` is an object of `TargetClass`.

So in my example, `target` could be the Property `Chief` and `field["Chief"]` could be `"23|John Doe"`

But when I try to assign an object of `MyBaseClass` to the Property `Chief`(or Product) I receive an error that the conversion from MyBaseClass to Chief failed. But to use this in a generic fashion I do want to use this method **on any Object that is derived from `MyBaseClass`.**

Comment: Instead of "new MyBaseClass { Id = id, Name=name };" do "(MyBaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(target.PropertyType)"

Comment: That did work. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you try to assign instance of a base class (`MyBaseClass`) to the property which expects instance of child class (`Person`). If you can be sure that all classes inherited from `MyBaseClass` has parameterless public constructor - create new instance of expected type via reflection and cast it to `MyBaseClass`:

```
foreach (var field in Fields) {
    var target=targetType.GetProperty(field.Key);
    if (field.Value.indexOf("|")>0) {
       int id=int.Parse(field.Value.Split('|')[0]);
       string name=field.Value.Split('|')[1];
       var baseObj = (MyBaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(target.PropertyType);
       baseObj.Id = id;
       baseObj.Name = name;
       target.SetValue(dest, baseObj);
    } else {
       target.SetValue(dest,field.Value);
  }
}
```